# Getting a fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock! with a simple test scenario

Tags: go

I am trying to repro an issue and came to a minimum use case with the following code. If I close all the channels (bypassing the i == 0 test), things are working as expected. Wg state decrements and done is triggered, main exits fine. When I skip closing one of these channel (on purpose), I expect the main routine to wait while the waitgroup semaphore will block indefinitely in this case. Instead, I am getting an error: "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!". Why is that? I must have missed something fundamental or this the runtime being overzealous?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

const N int = 4

func main() {

    done := make(chan struct{})
    defer close(done)

    fmt.Println("Beginning...")

    chans := make([]chan int, N)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        chans[i] = make(chan int)
        go func(i int) { // p0
            defer wg.Done()
            for m := range chans[i] {
                fmt.Println("Received ", m)
            }
            fmt.Println("Ending p", i)
        }(i)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        done <- struct{}{} // signal main that we are done
    }()

    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        fmt.Println("Closing c", i)
        if i != 0 { // Skip #0 so wg doesn't reach '0'
            close(chans[i])
        }
    }

    <-done // wait to receive signal from anonymous join function
    fmt.Println("Ending.")
}
```

**UPDATE:** I edited the code to avoid the race condition. Still getting this error.

The `if i != 0` is there because it's intentional. I want the wg.Wait to block forever (with its semaphore never reaching 0.) Why can't I do that? It seems the same as if I were using `<-done` without a matching `done <- struct{}{}` somewhere else. Would the compiler complain too in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's going on:

- The first `go func(i int) {` goroutine does not exit because `chans[0]` is not closed.
- Because the goroutine does not exit, `wg.Done` is not called.
- The call to `wg.Wait()` blocks forever because of the previous point.
- Main blocks forever because the signal is not sent to `done`.

You can fix the deadlock by removing the `if i != 0 {`, but there is another issue. There is a race on the wait group. It's possible that wg.Done() is called before wg.Add(1) is called.  Call wg.Add() before starting the goroutine to avoid the race.

Comment: I updated the code with your comment about race condition. I intentionally put `if i == 0` for wg to block forever. Why shouldn't I be able to never decrement its semaphore to 0?

Comment: If wg.Wait never returns, then the program does not send a value to `done`.  If the program does not send a value to `done`, then main blocks indefinitely.  The runtime prints an error because all goroutines are blocked. No forward progress can be made.

Comment: Interesting. So in order for main() to rever return I should use `for {...}` instead of `done := make(chan struct{}); <-done` (I am getting the same deadlock error with the latter.)

Comment: The code `done := make(chan struct{}); <-done` is one way to prevent main from exiting.  The empty select statement `select {}` is simpler and clearer. The empty for statement `for {}` is not a way to prevent main from exiting because it consumes CPU time as it spins.  If main does not exit, then your program deadlocks.  The runtime does not detect the deadlock when `for {}` is used, but it's still a deadlock.

Comment: @JohnDifool are you doing all this on play.golang??? If you are they won't let you use their play tool to run never ending stuff and it will always end with dead lock

Comment: You wrote: "The code `done := make(chan struct{}); <-done` is one way to prevent main from exiting" but when I do that, I still get "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!". And when I use `select {}`, same issue. I agree about cpu usage, but how do I stop the runtime from moaning about the deadlock then?

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want the runtime to complain when the program is deadlocked? There's usually no point in continuing to run a program when the program is blocked indefinitely.

Comment: Hmmm... I think I went too far in my quest of minimalizing my original use case. I found somewhere on google group what seems to be the reason for what I end up getting with select: "...it's just that that rule [select blocking on nil] is superseded by another which says at least one goroutine must be able to make progress. " So blocking main is fine, as long as I have another go routine doing some real work.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement in your for loop doesn't let the last channel close, so your `goroutine` is left waiting on something to happen to `chans[i]` which will block the `defer wg.Done()` from ever happening which in turn will never let `wg.Wait()` finish WHICH THENNNNN will never let `done <- struct{}{}` get signalled

So in short, your `if statement` in your loop is not closing the last channel and causing a deadlock because nobody can do nothing.

As @CodingPickle did point out, move your `wg.Add(1)` to the beginning of your `for loop` to prevent any race conditions

http://play.golang.org/p/j1D5LZGUhd